# How many different bluetooth devices can be connected to Laptop

Tags: bluetooth

So from what I read, it sounds like the general rule of thumb is that 7 devices could be connected to my laptop for bluetooth purposes. And from other threads I read there is a difference between types of bluetooth devices and how they connect.  I am no expert and want to confirm before I go make a bunch of purchases that may be worthless.

Basically, I am a big fan of bluetooth and normally connect my bluetooth earphones to all my devices for music. But now I am trying to get my new laptop station setup. I want to get a bluetooth mouse and bluetooth 10-key pad for my laptop. I even hear monitors can be bluetooth as well? Thing is, I want to connect them all via bluetooth if possible and avoid USB since I am using a laptop instead of a desktop and am on the move a bunch.

Would I be able to connect and use bluetooth earphones, mouse, 10-key, and monitors all at the same time? (Up to 7 devices I assume?)

The reason I ask is I don't want to go out and buy all this stuff to only find out I can only use 1 device at a time. I know when I connect my earbuds to my phone, no other bluetooth earbuds can be connected. So I want to avoid that type of situation with my laptop. I figured my laptop and phone would both be considered "Host" devices so should act simialrly?

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: In few words: that is correct for old Bluetooth 1 and 2 specifications. For modern Bluetooth 4 and 5 that is wrong in common way. There are 2 connection types: Audio and data. In legacy Bluetooth there only 1 audio and up to 7 data connections allowed. In modern Bluetooth this limitation has been removed (I do repeat - that is just very short description).